# Computing the differential

Tags: differential-geometry

**Assumption(s):**

> Let $(\rho, M(n,\mathbb{C}))$ be a representation of the group $G = SU(n)$ where $\rho(g)A := gAg^{T}$ for $A\in M(n,\mathbb{C}),g\in G$

**Problem:** I want to compute the differential $\frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0}  \text{exp}(tg)A\text{exp}(tg^{T})$. I'm however stuck. Most problems of this form (I've seen) use the chain rule, but this doesn't seem to be the case here (?).

How to approach this problem (or maybe more general: type of problem)?

Comment: Here are the key words: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation

Comment: Okay. So I can write it as a composition of the adjoint representation and the right translation map $r_{g^{T}g}$ and then use the chain rule? I obtain something like $gAg^{T}g - Ag^{T}gg$.

Comment: no you are looking at the adjoint representation. There is no translation involved.

Comment: The result in my comment is false. However I don't see why this is the adjoint, since the group is $SU$ and not $SO$.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using $g$ for both an element of the group and an element of its Lie algebra; that will be confusing in the long term. Better to write elements of the Lie algebra as $X$, so the differential you want to compute is the differential of

$$\exp (t X) A \exp (- t X).$$

(Your second term is also wrong; you presumably want the inverse of $\exp (tX)$, which is $\exp (-tX)$.)

This is easy to do formally and the formal argument can be justified in various ways. For example, write

$$\exp (tX) = 1 + tX + O(t^2).$$

Then

$$\exp (tX) A \exp( -tX) = (1 + tX + O(t^2)) A (1 - tX + O(t^2))$$

and we can compute that this is

$$(A + t XA + O(t^2))(1 - tX + O(t^2)) = A + t (XA - AX) + O(t^2).$$

So the first-order term is the commutator $[X, A] = XA - AX$, and that's the derivative.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't want to compute the differential of $\text{exp}(tX)A\text{exp}(-tX)$ (I know this is ad), but $\text{exp}(tX)A\text{exp}(tX^{T})$. However the  idea seems to work also in this case.

Comment: You should note that your group is $SO$ not something arbitrary. In this group the inverse has some special properties. In particular $g^{-1} = g^{T}$ in SO and for the Lie algebra you have $X^{T} = -X$. So you are in the adjoint case really.

Comment: But the group is $SU$ meaning $g^{-1} = \overline{g}^{T}$?

Comment: @fromnowon: yes, that's correct. And as DBS says, on the Lie algebra level this means $X^T = -X$ (where $T$ is the adjoint, not the transpose).